# Referenciar variáveis no HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html5, bootstrap, golang

Eu sou iniciante em programação web e tenho uma dúvida (acredito eu) bem simples:
Eu queria saber se há alguma forma de referenciar variáveis de uma linguagem backend (no meu caso estou utilizando Go-lang) no HTML? Estou utilizando o framework Bootstrap para construir o frontend.

Abraços!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

de fato há duas formas bem comuns, normalmente isso é feito através de uma view engine da sua linguagem, da qual usa uma sintaxe própria, é uma das funcionalidades que ela prove é justamente a realização de acesso de variáveis que são passadas do seu back-end para sua view e também pode ser realizada outras operações, no caso do Go, eu vejo as pessoas utilizando essa aqui: https://github.com/sipin/gorazor.

A outra forma seria através de requisições ajax para seu back-end que iriam te retornar dados e com isso você iria realizar tarefas relevantes para montar seu front-end de acordo com os dados retornados.